# Magento SQL get product sku with the right active category in multishops

Tags: sql, magento, magento-1.9

I'm traying to get product sku that are displayed on the website with the category of that product.

Output:

```
+-------------+------------+
| sku         | category_n |
+-------------+------------+
|      855202 |      test1 |
|     87972_k |      test2 |
|      887997 |      test1 |
+-------------+------------+
```

I have look at these tables:

```
catalog_category_product
catalog_product_entity
catalog_category_entity
catalog_category_entity_varchar
```

The query give a lot of rows back for just one sku i get about 100 records back. i don't see which one is the right category that is active right now..

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    "catalog_category_product" as ccp 
JOIN
    "catalog_product_entity" as cpe ON "cpe.entity_id" = "ccp.product_id"
JOIN  
    "catalog_category_entity" as cat ON "cat.entity_id" = "ccp.category_id"
JOIN 
    "catalog_category_entity_varchar" as cv on cat.entity_id = cv."entity_id"
```

Comment: please provide some sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your are using a mysql database 
Try Don't using quote around object name (table and column name)

```
SELECT * 
FROM catalog_category_product as ccp 
JOIN catalog_product_entity as cpe ON cpe.entity_id = ccp.product_id
JOIN catalog_category_entity as cat ON cat.entity_id = ccp.product_id
JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar as cv on cat.entity_id = cv.entity_id
```

Comment: then update your question add  a proper data sample  .. with data for all the column involved  and  the expected  result coherent with the data sample .. (anyway  the use of double quote in mysql don't work)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using left join

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    "catalog_category_product" as ccp 
Left JOIN
    "catalog_product_entity" as cpe ON "cpe.entity_id" = "ccp.product_id"
Left JOIN  
    "catalog_category_entity" as cat ON "cat.entity_id" = "ccp.category_id"
Left JOIN 
    "catalog_category_entity_varchar" as cv on cat.entity_id = cv."entity_id"
```